# Picasso callback not called

Tags: android, callback, imageview, picasso

i am new to android world  and trying to load the image using Picasso in to ImageView.
Here is the code .

````
Picasso.with(HomeScreenActivity.getInstance().getBaseContext())
.load(mFile)
.fit().memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).
networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE).
into(imageView, new callback() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess() {
     Log.d("picasso-service", " onSuccess: ");    
  }
  @Override
 public void onError() {   
       Log.d("picasso-service", "onError ");
 }
});```


**OnSuccess or OnError callbacks are not triggered**
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `HomeScreenActivity.getInstance().getBaseContext()`, just use `this` or `HomeScreenActivity.this`

```
Picasso.with(HomeScreenActivity.this)
            .load(uri)
            .fit().memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).
            networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE).
    into(imageView, new Callback() {
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    Log.d("picasso-service", " onSuccess: ");
}

@Override
public void onError() {
    Log.d("picasso-service", "onError ");
}});
```